# Как добавить авто-инкрементирование?

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь добавить свойство авто-инкрементирования в таблицу **person** для поля *person_id*:
Запрос ниже.

`ALTER TABLE person MODIFY person_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Но ошибка: `ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'person_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'pk_person_id' of table 'glava.favourite_food'
mysql>`

*table* **person**:

```
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person_id   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| fname       | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lname       | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender      | enum('M','F')        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| birth_date  | date                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address     | varchar(30)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city        | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state       | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country     | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postal_code | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

*table* **favourite_food**:

```
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| food      | varchar(20)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Почему нельзя изменить и каким образом этого все-таки добиться?

Comment: Ключ не позволяет. Попробуйте убрать внешний ключ, изменить колонку и снова добавить внешний ключ

Comment: @Skywave Но я все делаю по книге. Странно

Comment: Автоинкремент НЕ МОЖЕТ быть компонентом внешней ссылки. Поскольку его значение недетерминировано, что для внешнего ключа есть нонсенс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед выполнением альтера отключите проверку внешних ключей:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

А после альтера верните назад:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Проверял вот такими запросами [в отладчике](https://rextester.com/l/mysql):

```
drop table if exists favourite_food_1012533;
drop table if exists person_1012533;

create table person_1012533 (
    person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
create table favourite_food_1012533 (
    id INT,
    person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    INDEX person_id_idx (person_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person_1012533(person_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE person_1012533 MODIFY person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

show create table person_1012533;
```

Всё ОК!